# 2 problems with numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I set a NSMutableArray in viewcontrolller.m

```
barcodeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in viewcontroller.h like this:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    NSString *string;
    NSString *barcode;
    NSArray *array;
    NSMutableArray *barcodeArray;

}
```

Than i add an object like this:

```
if ([barcodeArray indexOfObject:barcode] != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"%@",barcode);
    NSLog(@"object zit er al in");

}
else {
    [barcodeArray addObject:barcode];
    [_tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@",barcodeArray);
    NSLog(@"object zit er nog niet in");

}
```

When i set numberOfRowsInSection to return [barcodeArray count]; the function cellForRowAtIndexPath isnt called. it's like the barcodeArray count is null.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [barcodeArray count];

}
```

When i set numberofRowsinSection to return 1; just to test.. i get a cell with (null) in it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"aangeroepen");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[barcodeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);


    return cell;
}
```

Here's my log:

```
2013-01-17 07:57:04.139 Scanner[21865:c07] (
    123456
)   **// NSMutableArray when i add the barcode**
2013-01-17 07:57:04.140 Scanner[21865:c07] object zit er nog niet in
2013-01-17 07:57:05.485 Scanner[21865:c07] viewdidload
2013-01-17 07:57:05.488 Scanner[21865:c07] aangeroepen
2013-01-17 07:57:05.489 Scanner[21865:c07] (null) **// NSMutableArray in cell.textLabel.text**
```

EDIT:

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[barcodeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"celltext:%@", cell.textLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"barcodearray%@", [barcodeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    NSLog(@"objectatindex:0:%@", [barcodeArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@"indexpath.row:%d", indexPath.row);

Log:



2013-01-17 08:27:28.838 Scanner[21978:c07] celltext:(null)
2013-01-17 08:27:28.839 Scanner[21978:c07] barcodearray(null)
2013-01-17 08:27:28.839 Scanner[21978:c07] objectatindex:0:(null)
2013-01-17 08:27:28.839 Scanner[21978:c07] indexpath.row:0
```

Comment: Where are you doing this `barcodeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`? Can you put a breakpoint or log message on that statement? It probably isn't being executed.

Comment: I think my method of sending is wrong. i am going to try this method:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 1):

I have a very strong feeling that your `barcodeArray` only has a local scope in your method with 
if/else statements. I think that you need to retain the `barcodeArray`, because it's null in your other methods.

Can you do an `NSLog(@"%d", [barcodeArray count]);` in your `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method and show what that prints? That'll help confirm if it's an issue with how you allocated and retain the array. If that's the problem...then in your header file, you would write,

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* barcodeArray;` and in your implementation file, you would write`` `@synthesize barcodeArray = _barcodeArray; ``

Then, you would do, `self.barcodeArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

and everywhere you use `barcodeArray`, add self before it. By retaining the object (with the property in your header file... retain = strong), you can now access is throughout the class. It shouldn't be null anymore in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRows` methods.

EDIT:

In your code, you're doing

```
[barcodeArray addObject:barcode];
```

This should be

```
[self.barcodeArray addObject:barcode];
```

nowhere in your code should you have `barcodeArray` -- you should only have `self.barcodeArray`.

Comment: It need not be necessary. I have used the bar code as string. Although i agree that it is just a set of numbers (integer).

Comment: No because i set it i commented in the answer under here

Comment: NSLog(@"barcode:%@", barcode); 2013-01-17 08:07:17.944 Scanner[21893:c07] barcode:123456

Comment: are you getting the object on trying the above answer?

Comment: I think the problem is that barcodeArray is null in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and it's unexplainable why that is. What does [barcodeArray count] return in your numberOfSections method? I have a very strong feeling the problem is that your barcodeArray is null, and to fix it, you need to retain your barcodeArray object.

Comment: Could you please explain how i do that

Comment: Maybe you could look at the code completely and look whats wrong

Comment: I see the problem, updating my answer

Comment: Okay, let me get back at you in a few minutes. going to test the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22885/discussion-between-babboe-and-rohan-agarwal)

Answer (score 0):

The barcode is nil . Set something in the barcode ie; `barCode = @"11225544";` and try.

Comment: it isnt because i do this:
 barcode = [a objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"barcode:%@", barcode);
2013-01-17 08:07:17.944 Scanner[21893:c07] barcode:123456

Comment: try this and tell what happened if ([barcodeArray indexOfObject:barcode] == NSNotFound)

Comment: what is this?
    NSLog(@"object zit er al in");

Comment: That function is where i check if the nsmutablearray already contains the barcode or not

Comment: have you allocated the mutable array?